# Migration issue from spring 3.1.2 to spring 4

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-jms

We are try to migrate from Spring 3.1.2 to Spring 4.1.2
After migration, when running tomcat we are facing below exception,
This issue is caused by our spring-jms dependency.
As per my knowledge, this class "MappingJacksonMessageConverter" is available only in spring 3, in spring 4 the class is MappingJackson**2**MessageConverter.
I'm not sure which part of spring code is loading this class MappingJacksonMessageConverter.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jms/support/converter/MappingJacksonMessageConverter
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3116)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1344)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1825)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.convertClassValues(AnnotationReadingVisitorUtils.java:73)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotationMetadataReadingVisitor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:276)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:263)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:509)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:277)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:231)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:190)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:173)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:674)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at com.walmart.platform.config.PlatformContextLoaderListener.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(PlatformContextLoaderListener.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at com.walmart.platform.config.PlatformContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PlatformContextLoaderListener.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5077)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJacksonMessageConverter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: "I'm not sure which part of spring code is loading this" - so how should we know? Start searching your application contexts at "com.walmart.platform.config.PlatformContextLoaderListener".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a wrong version of some dependencies, maybe they are not migrated, so you have to see the dependencies table of the Spring 4.1.2 in the maven central, this table contains the lowest version compatible with the Spring version you want.